# Mixing Google Maps custom overlays with Backbone Views

Tags: google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, underscore.js, prototypal-inheritance

**TL;DR**

Is `PinView.prototype = _.extend(PinView.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype)` the "proper" way to have a Backbone View inherit from another "class"?

**Long read**

We're redoing our site using Backbone and are working on including some mapping functionality.

I've got a Backbone view that handles placing `<div>`s onto specific points within the browser window; this seems like a natural thing to extend in order have Google's Map API place them on geographical coordinates.

According to the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html), in order to generate a custom overlay you create a new object and set the prototype for that object to a new instance of google.maps.OverlayView.  You then implement three functions on top of that object so that the object responds to:

`onAdd`

`draw`

`onRemove`

Where `onAdd` is responsible for generating the HTML and then applying it on top of the Map.  This subsequently calls `draw` which positions the element correctly according to the LatLng pairs and bounds you've provided. `onRemove` gets called when you want to get rid of your layer.

So I've modified my View to include these three methods (which just call render and unrender and are bound to my collection).  And then to make "the magic happen" I'm doing:

`PinView.prototype = _.extend(PinView.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype)`

Does this look right?  I can post the code for the View and the Model on which it's based, but honestly, they're irrelevant to this example -- the code works and I'm able to place custom `div`s generated through Backbone model, view and controller components on the map without a issue, what I'm asking I guess (and maybe this question is more apropos for programmers.se, so let me know and I'll move it).

This seems to be the easiest way to make my PinView both a Backbone View and a Google Maps OverlayView, but I'm not 100% comfortable with prototypal inheritance to know if I'm doing something "wrong" or breaking something somewhere down the road.

Comment: Hm, it might be actually cleaner to make a PinView as BackboneView with google maps OverlayView as a property on the PinView linked to that overlay. Not sure about internals of google classes as they are bit obscured with all the minifications - but i think i'd rather avoid mixing these two as they are kind of classes of different Type and who knows what might happen (Though if it works please let us know!). Something I'd totally love to try playing with a bit more - if I only had the time Eh!

Comment: It is working, I guess my question was more "is this how you do multiple inheritance using prototypial inheritance" than "should I really be doing this?"  The Backbone stuff is super clean and wel thought out so I'm not worried about some sort of Prototype namespace collision, and while the Google source is minified, when you're playing with it in the debugger, the Prototype for the OverlayView() object is actually super simple as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice idea! I'm usually a bit sceptical about weather or not you're 'correct' when things work so if you haven't run into a showstopper and the overlays shows up and does what the're supposed to do I'd say you are.

One thing to check out closer, though:

This isn't (and can't) be "real" multiple inheritance - that concept isn't really relevant in a prototype based language: one implementation of a method will inevitable "win" and overwrite the other implementation, at least when using `_.extend()`

This means that if there are members or methods with the same names in `Backbone.View` and `google.maps.OverlayView` the one *last* in your `_.extend()` call will be the one that takes over. But when I inspect them using Chrome's Developer Tools I didn't see any obvious collision of this kind.

So my recommendation: continue using this, just test a lot. I'd love to see an example of this technique some time.

Answer (score 1):

Ah!  So I've been doing the above, but it's never felt right.

Then I found [this discussion on a Backbone group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/backbonejs/QGz6UAajUH0) which leads me to the following:

```
var MyView = (function(){
    var view = function(){
        Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    view.extend = Backbone.View.extend;

    _.extend(view.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype, [other prototypes...], { [VIEW DEFINITION] });

    return view;
}());
```

This way if we need to override any of the definitions in a class we're `extend`ing from, we can since it's earlier in the `_.extend` chain (later definitions overwrite earlier definitions).

I'm working on 'extending' `extend` to keep track of the "parent" object's references that would be overridden and providing a method to call them still (like Python's `super` call).  I haven't decided if this should be done through monkey-patching, an intercepter pattern (via underscore's `_.tap()` method or something else, but I think it'll add a lot of flexibility.

This would allow you to define an `initialize` view in your "parent" class which could be called by doing something like `_.super('ParentClass', 'initialize');` at the end of the "child" class's `initialize` routine...

Comment: tkone: thanks for your updated answer, could you please post your working code, i'm also trying to use OverlayView with backbone view and unsuccessfull at it.. i liked this way, but for some reason i can't seem getting it to work.

Comment: In later versions of underscore (eg. 1.1.2), `_.extend` doesn't work as expected. You'll have to use a custom extend method (I copied it from underscore 1.0.0)

Comment: @Koen. because like semver? why bother!

Comment: @tkone what do you mean?

Comment: @Koen. semver would dictate a non-deprecated API CANNOT change functionality within a major version. So if `_.extend` works differenly in 1.1.2 than it did in anything in 1.x prior (or following), it's broken the semver contract. Underscore is notorious for this behavior. (A reason I no longer user underscore)