# backbone.js + google.maps api v3 + overlayview = prototyping using backbone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js

I've read:

[Mixing Google Maps custom overlays with Backbone Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102762/mixing-google-maps-custom-overlays-with-backbone-views)

and tried implementing and toying with it as i need to use custom overlays as views,and i already use backbone.js

```
var Label = function(){
        Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
        this.newInit();
    };

    Label.extend = Backbone.View.extend;

    _.extend(Label.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype,{
        newInit: function(){
         this.setMap(this.options.map);
        },
        onAdd: function(){...},
        onRemove: function(){...},
        draw: function(){...}
    });

    var label_view = new LabelView({map: map});
    label_view.bindTo('some_event', {name: 'some_event_occured'});
```

And from what i tested, the "draw" method isn't called, despite its supposed to override it.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution:

```
var Label = function(){
        Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
        google.maps.OverlayView.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

and instead of

```
newInit: function(){
```

use:

```
initialize: function(options){
```

Hope this helps